# Estimate Survival Function from hazard function --- an inconsistent result between basehaz and survfit function

Tags: r, survival

I am trying to caculate survival function in a time dependent covariates Cox model  from its baseline hazard function. However, my program gives a different result compared with `survfit`. Based on the formula

$S(t)=\exp(-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_{0}(\mu)\exp[\hat{\beta}Z(\mu)]d\mu$

result should match. I just need this program for illustration but speed. The data I used can be download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3824701/stackexchange/tmp.Rdata) and program have been attached. [Figure 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3824701/stackexchange/tmp.png) shown the graph generated by the program below.

```
library(survival)
fit.cox  <- coxph( Surv(t1,t2,event) ~ x, data = sim$data)
lambda0 <- basehaz(fit.cox, centered = F)  # Estimated Baseline Hazard Function

# Caculate Survival Function
t.cut   <- sim$t.cut
    lambda0 <- rbind(lambda0, c(0,0) )
    x       <- sim$x[1, ]
beta    <- fit.cox$coefficients
pred    <- exp( x * beta )

#Baseline Hazard Function
lambda0.fun  <- function(t) {
    approx(x = lambda0$time, y = lambda0$hazard, xout = t)$y
}

#Hazard Function
lambda.fun <- function(t){
  which.t <- sum(t >= t.cut) 
  lambda0.fun(t) * pred[which.t]  
}

#Survival Function
survival.fun <- function(t){
  cum.hazard <- integrate(Vectorize(lambda.fun), 0, t, subdivisions = 1e3L)
  exp(- cum.hazard$value)
}

#Test Program
test <-sim$data[1,]
s.est <- Vectorize(survival.fun)(seq(0,2,0.1))
s.est2 <- survfit(fit.cox, newdata = test, id = id, 
              se.fit = F, type = "efron")
plot(s.est2, xlim = c(0,2))
points(seq(0,2,0.1), s.est)
```

Comment: You are right, something seems strange. You might have to dig into the `survival:::survfit.coxph` function, or contact the package maintainer. A few minor quibbles: you should use piecewise constant interpolation of the hazard function, and summation is probably better than integration, but these changes won't fix your main problem.

Answer (score 2):

After looking for the source code of `basehaz.S`, I've got the reason why I am wrong here. First `basehaz` simply compute cumulate hazard function $\Lambda_0(t)$ by using `survfit` instead of  instantaneous hazard function $\lambda_0(t)$

Second the main code for `basehaz.S` is

```
    sfit<-survfit(fit)
    H<- -log(sfit$surv)
```

Then it's wrong to use this function to estimate a time dependent covariates Cox model (which require `id` option in `survfit`).

I think we should avoid to use the `basehaz` function becuase it exists only because Prof. Therneau try to comfort SAS programmers as he described in the document of `basehaz` function.

Answer (score 0):

They give the same results. Try this:

```
    H0 <- basehaz(fit.cox, centered=T)
    h0 <- unique(-log(survfit(fit.cox)$surv))
```

You will see that the two results are the same.
If you want to get the survival instead of the cumulative hazard:

```
    S0 <- exp(-H0)
    s0 <- survfit(fit.cox)$surv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing `exp(-H0)` where `H0=basehaz(fit.cox, centered=T)` also changed the time values.

a solution to this was:

```
H0=basehaz(fit.cox, centered=T)
timeS0=H0$time
survS0=exp(-H0$hazard)
survModel=cbind.data.frame(timeS0,survS0)
```